# Customized ABPeoplePickerNavigationController like viber, whatsapp

Tags: objective-c, ios

How to display ABPeoplePickerNavigationController like viber, where viber icon is appearing in front of those contacts who are already using it. Please check the screenshot. Here is the code what i am trying to do but facing issues ...

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33.0f/255.0f green:54.0f/255.0f blue:63.0f/255.0f alpha:0.20f];

    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    UIView *view = picker.topViewController.view; 
    UITableView *tableView = nil;
    for(UIView *uv in view.subviews)
    {
        if([uv isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]])
        {
            tableView = (UITableView*)uv; 

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logoIcon"]];

            NSLog(@"NumberOfSection<--->%d",[tableView numberOfSections]);

            NSLog(@"NumberOfRows=%dInSection=%d",[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i], i);

            for (int i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfSections]; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++)
                {
                    UITableViewCell *celll = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i]];

                    celll.accessoryView = imageView;

                    NSLog(@"currentIndex=>%@",celll.accessoryView);

                    celll = nil;
                }
            }

            break;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` to do what you're trying to do. I recommend just creating your own custom `UIViewController` and making the contacts tableview yourself. It is easy to do and this way you can customize the cells in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` without having to do any hacking.

Comment: Is this still true for iOS 7?

Comment: Yes. There are plenty of open source components on github though to get you started.

Comment: Could you specify some? I tried: [MultiContactsSelector-ios] (https://github.com/sergiomtzlosa/MultiContactsSelector-ios), and [THContactPicker] (https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/THContactPicker), but they didn't provide me a way to see how to fetch the all the contacts in the AddressBook without duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates?

Comment: I mean that I get contacts I have on the iPhone and also contacts I have on iCloud to appear twice, even though they are actually the same contact (with same name and same phone number).

Comment: @roi.holtzman this is an entirely different question which you should ask separately. You may end up having to just do this yourself by filtering linked contacts which you get using `ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople`.