# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController UITableView Index

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm subclassing `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` and I want to customize it's UITableView right index, the letters on the right side of the table view.

I want to add my own symbols.

How can I access this array?

Thanks!

Comment: It would involve replacing the people picker's table's delegate with a class of your own, or swizzling.  Either way, not pretty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customized ABPeoplePickerNavigationController like viber, whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362936/customized-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-like-viber-whatsapp)

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states:

> The ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class does not support subclassing.